# Hibernate: what is a good way to create a database during automatic build

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, gradle

I need to do the following as part of automatic build process of the Apache CXF-based RESTful server:

1. Create database
2. Create several tables
3. Populate those tables
4. ... other unrelated stuff

What is the best way to go about it? I'm using Maven for my builds but willing to try Gradle if needed.
Thanks!

Comment: you can do it at startup of the application for sure but dont know if you can do it at the building process.

Comment: Yes I understand that.  I could even have a separate application run once during the build but I thought there must be a better way.